# Can't manage run the completed Spring Yummy Noodle Bar tutorials

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run the completed version of the Yummy Noodle Bar tutorials (REST + WebApp) locally, so that I can dig through the code a little bit on my 2*6hr bus rides this weekend.

- http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/
- http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

According to both guides, the finished code is available:

```
$ cd ../6/complete
$ ./gradlew tomcatRunWar
```

However, both versions do not run for me and give build errors.

Can anyone else manage to run these? Is there anything wrong with my Java version or Path?

```
2014-09-19 09:36:10 ERROR ContextLoader:319 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [com/yummynoodlebar/config/SecurityConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
```

Comment: Looking at the stack trace you are using a newer java version (java 8 probably) which isn't supported on the used spring version (3.2 if I'm not mistaken). Downgrade java or upgrade spring in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the error (updated the Spring-core and Spring-mvc to 4.1.0). But now I am getting a different error: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. -- I have found solutions for this before but it basically removes all dependencies which means some classes will not compile as they are referencing objects from these paths.

Comment: It is an error or a warning, normally one is just picked. Upgrade to slf4j 1.7.7 also make sure you upgrade ALL spring jars to that version never mix versions of frameworks that is trouble waiting to happen.